# Simplifying a short Boolean expression

Tags: boolean-algebra

\begin{align*}
A’B + A’B’C + ABC’C’ + AB’ + AB’C’
&= A’B + A’B’C + ABC’ + AB’ + AB’C’ \\
&= A’(B +B’C) + ABC’ + AB’(C’+1) \\
&= ???
\end{align*}

I'm stuck after this. Please help me!!

Answer (score 1):

From the first line, I get the following [Karnaugh-Veitch map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map):

[image]

The colored areas correspond to the terms of your equation.

Three blocks with two squares each suffice to cover the colored area:

$$A C' + A' B + B' C $$

An alternative expression:

$$A B' + B C' + A' C $$